# Responsive column

Tags: html, css

Which methods is recommended to accomplish the following css display in regard to responsive web design.

I really only have one requirement. Maximum of three columns. So if there were 20 letters, they'd be equally divided between the three columns.

SCSS is to be used. Also Flexbox and CSS Grids are welcome. I'd like to not use Bootstrap (I know the grid system exists).

Screen width < 1000px:

```
A D G
B E H
C F
```

Screen width < 500px

```
A E
B F
C G
D H
```

Screen width < 200px:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Here is a codepen with some starting code. I can't seem to figure out a good enough system for this.

https://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/NjgvNa

I was thinking of using CSS Grids, however this doesn't make it dynamic anymore (hard coded positioning). The items on this list will change.

Comment: Did you try it with using bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/.
You can use Cols property and get above result easily

Comment: If you are going to write three different sets of rules based on your pixel widths (which are device specific and so rather useless and lacking in meaning), you can well use CSS Grids -- that's what they're for. And as to pixel widths -- I'd recommend you to use `em` units for widths in your media queries (like `@media(max-width: 20em) { /* ... */ }`) instead of pixels. Or just go by aspect ratio, which may be even better: `@media(min-aspect-ratio: 1) { /* ... */ }`. There are [other properties you can use as well](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), but you probably know these.

Comment: You are required to post your example code here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow. In addition, SO is for asking specific questions about specific problems, not for asking opinion nor for asking us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to specifically achieve what I'm after it to create two separate columns (each containing A to H). One with three and the other with two (which turns into one). One hidden and the other shown then vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for this but it works.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  div {
    background: red;
  }
  el {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div {
    background: grey;
  }
  el {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  div {
    background: lime;
  }
  el {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

el {
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  margin: 2em 0em;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <el>A</el>
  <el>B</el>
  <el>C</el>
  <el>D</el>
  <el>E</el>
  <el>F</el>
  <el>G</el>
  <el>H</el>
</div>
```

Also, for `n` columns, you can do:

```
el {
  width: calc(100%/n);
}
```